# How to use logical values to access elements of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, element

Say I have this data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(rep(1:5, each=5), nrow=5))
```

Say I want to square all values that are greater than `3` and put these values back into the x.

I identify the values that are greater than `3` by:

```
x > 3
```

Then how can I reference these values in x? Doing `x[x>3]` returns a vector of integers, not a data frame.

Note that I am more so interested in this particular problem of `x[x>3]` and not as much the actual application that I included simply as motivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or,

```
> x[x>3] <- (x[x>3])^2
> x
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3 16 25
2  1  2  3 16 25
3  1  2  3 16 25
4  1  2  3 16 25
5  1  2  3 16 25
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use matrix indexing:

```
ind <- which(x > 3, arr.ind = TRUE)
x[ind] <- x[ind] * x[ind] ## or x[ind] <- x[ind]^2
x
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  1  2  3 16 25
# 2  1  2  3 16 25
# 3  1  2  3 16 25
# 4  1  2  3 16 25
# 5  1  2  3 16 25
```

Alternatively, you can do `replace(x, x > 3, x[x > 3]^2)`, but remember that this doesn't actually modify your "x" object so it needs to be reassigned.

Comment: I think `x[ind] <- x[ind]^2L` will be better especially if the matrix is pretty big.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I don't know where the performance jump will kick in, but on 1000x10000, the results are pretty much identical for me with all 3 options here so far. The other answer is the fastest if x is a `matrix` instead of a `data.frame`